# Probability of rolling two dice multiple times

Tags: probability, probability-theory, uniform-distribution

For this question, I know that the sample space is $6^3$, and that (1,6), (2,5), (3,4) are the possibilities for rolling a sum of seven. I'm not sure how to continue after that. Here is what I have so far. Can anyone please help me out?

Suppose we repeatedly roll two fair six-sided dice, considering the sum of the
two values showing each time. What is the probability that the first time the sum is
exactly 7 is on the third roll?

$S = 6^3 = 216$

$(1, 6) (2, 5) (3,4)$ are the possibilities for the sum eqaul to 7

Comment: How sample space is $6^3$? It should be $6^2$ if you are rolling 2 dice.

Comment: cuz we are rolling it 3 times

Comment: Also consider possibilities of $(6,1)(5,2)(4,3)$

Comment: I dont understand rolling 3 times. How?

Answer (score 4):

There are $6^2=36$ possible outcomes for each roll of both dice. There are $6$ combinations that result in a sum of $7$, those you mentioned, and those also with digits reversed.

So the success probability is $\frac{6}{36}=\frac16$ and the failure probability is $\frac{30}{36}=\frac56$. You are saying there are two failures and one success, so that probability is:
$$\bigg(\frac56\bigg)^2\cdot\frac16=\frac{25}{216}$$

Comment: Yes, I see now, my mistake was that I considered (6,1) and (1,6) as the same thing. Now this all makes sense, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Best you consider the two dice indepenedly.

The ways to roll a 7 the become $(1,6),(2,5),(3,4),(4,3),(5,2),(6,1)$

There are 6 ways to roll a 7.

There are 36 combinations of outcomes from 2 dice.

The chance of getting a 7 on any roll then is $\frac {6}{36} = \frac {1}{6}.$
The chance of not getting a 7 on any roll then is $1- \frac {1}{6} = \frac {5}{6}.$

Now you need to calculate the likelihood of not getting a 6 on the first roll, not getting a 6 on the second roll and getting a 6 on the 3rd roll.

Comment: Oh, we are assuming duplicates?

Comment: No duplicates.  The two dice are independent entities.  $ (1,6)$ is a different roll from $(6,1).$ If it helps make one die red and the other white.

Comment: Oh, I see where I went wrong now. I assumed (1,6) and (6,1) were the same, so I treated it as one